# Android - change duration of In App purchases

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have an Android app that uses in app purchases in the form of subscriptions with a duration of 1 month or 1 year.

I want to create a new in app purchase which a **3 year renewable subscription** for example.

Is this possible?